# how to compile php5apache2_2.dll

Tags: php, apache, compilation, visual-c++-2008

I have compiled Apache 2.2 then compiled php5.3 with VC++9. I wish to run php5.3 as a module in the Apache which I compiled. Apache is running at port 80 but I can't configure httpd.conf because I need php5apache2_2.dll. I searched in the RELEASE_TS folder but not found. How to get this? I am using windows xp. Purpose is academic.

Comment: There are precompiled windows binaries on php.net

Comment: I know that. But I want to compile php and apache and then use. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I have only used precompiled so far. Not sure why you want to compile php yourself.

Comment: for academic purpose. I have made some changes and I intend to create my own extension in php

Comment: for academic purposes drop windows.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I got it. I compiled it with default setting of configure.js and the problem gone.